# integral transforms defined by polygons

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Are there any literature on operators of the form
\[ (Tf)(x) = \int K(x,y)f(y), dy\]
where $K(x,y)$ is the characteristic function of a **polygon** in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  I would like to know if the spectrum has ever been calculated.

For the lattice triangle, with vertices $(0,0),(0,\frac{\pi}{2}),(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$ the spectrum is $\frac{1}{4k+1}$, as found by Noam Elkies in

- *[On the sums $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (4k+1)^{-n}$](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0101168)*, Amer. Math. Monthly **110** no.7 (Aug.-Sep. 2003) 561–573, https://doi.org/10.2307/3647742